# Facebook Fangate

Tags: php, facebook

I am trying to make a simple fangate Facebook app, but i get stuck.
The page simply doesn`t show - it`s blank.
I found a code on internet and implemented it (also downloaded facebook sdk from github)
The Facebook Page URL (http) and Secure (https) are correct.
If I link index.php the page is blank, if I link the prelike.php or reveal.php the content is shown.
Does anyone know where might be the problem?
link to the facebook app :
https://www.facebook.com/pages/Testna-stran/136388943218474?id=136388943218474&sk=app_744205652262463

```
<?php
require 'facebook.php';

$app_id = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$app_secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => $app_id,
    'secret' => $app_secret,
    'cookie' => true
));


$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();

$page_id = $signed_request["page"]["id"];
$page_admin = $signed_request["page"]["admin"];
$like_status = $signed_request["page"]["liked"];
$country = $signed_request["user"]["country"];
$locale = $signed_request["user"]["locale"];

// The following statement does a test of $like_status and chooses which page to     display to the visitor
if ($like_status) {$a = file_get_contents("reveal.php");
echo ($a);
}
else {$a = file_get_contents("prelike.php");
echo ($a);
}

?>
```

Comment: your testpage is not published, can´t open it :(
did you try debugging in the browser? if the page is blank, then there´s usually an error in the code.

Comment: sorry... now it`s published

Comment: ...but there is no app, only the default apps photos/likes.

Comment: hmmm... I`ll still attend to write the code for "prelike.php" and "reveal.php" at the moment I left it as I found it on the internet with pictures(that should for fans and nonfans). I just dont know why the content of those pages are not shown.

Comment: did you restrict your app to specific countries?

Comment: problem solved ;) json extension was missing in PHP 5 on the server. thats why i got the 500 internal server error